# change 3-d to 2-d dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas iterates through a workbook and imports data from a list of worksheet names ('fb'). If the list only contains a single value then it adds that sheet to the data frame. If the list contains more than a single value, then it concatenates the worksheets into a single worksheet.

The issue is as currently coded the df2 returns a 3-d shape rather than 2-d. I have tried .melt and .unstack but must be using them incorrectly. The end result should be row=31, column=15. Code works perfectly fine if there are multiple worksheets. The addition of the if to check the list length creates the issue 'if len(fb) >= 2 else pd.DataFrame(df2)'

```
# create hr fb dataframe
# read data from list of worksheet
df2 = [pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s, skiprows=5, nrows=31, usecols='M:AA', header=None) for s in fb]
# merge above data into a single sheet
dfc2 = pd.concat(df2, ignore_index=True, sort=False) if len(fb) >= 2 else pd.DataFrame(df2)
# rename column index numbers
dfc2.columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5',
                'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11',
                'C12', 'C13', 'C14', 'C15']
# if column C contains a zero remove the row
dfc2 = dfc2[dfc2.C3 != 0]
# add additional blank columns to end
dfc2[colnum2] = ""
# clear columns containing useless data
dfc2.loc[:, 'C1'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C11'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C13'] = ""
# rearange column data to match final format needed
dfc2.loc[:, 'C23'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C5']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C5'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C14'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C17'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C15']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C15'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C27'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C3']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C3'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C3'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C7']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C7'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C7'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C27']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C27'] = ""
# end of hr fb dataframe creation
```

[image]

I have tried to implement solutions from the below answers to similar questions, but can't seem to get the format correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[converting 3D pandas dataframe to 2d [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815805/converting-3d-pandas-dataframe-to-2d)
[Reshape MultiIndex dataframe to tabular format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901513/reshape-multiindex-dataframe-to-tabular-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected by using Numpy reshape.

```
# create hr fb dataframe
# read data from list of worksheet
df2 = [pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=s, skiprows=5, nrows=31, usecols='M:AA', header=None) for s in fb]
# merge above data into a single sheet
dfc2 = pd.concat(df2, ignore_index=True, sort=False) if len(fb) >= 2 else pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df2, (31, 15)))
# rename column index numbers
dfc2.columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5',
                'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11',
                'C12', 'C13', 'C14', 'C15']
# if column C contains a zero remove the row
dfc2 = dfc2[dfc2.C3 != 0]
# add additional blank columns to end
dfc2[colnum2] = ""
# clear columns containing useless data
dfc2.loc[:, 'C1'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C11'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C13'] = ""
# rearange column data to match final format needed
dfc2.loc[:, 'C23'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C5']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C5'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C14'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C17'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C15']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C15'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C27'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C3']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C3'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C3'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C7']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C7'] = ""
dfc2.loc[:, 'C7'] = dfc2.loc[:, 'C27']
dfc2.loc[:, 'C27'] = ""
# end of hr fb dataframe creation
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to slice the array like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68970088/numpy-trouble-obtaining-a-2d-slice-of-3d-array), before returning. Since the shape is returning (1, 31, 15), you could modify it to be:

```
df[0, :, :].squeeze()
```

Comment: returns a TypeError "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple". 'if len(fb) >= 2 else pd.DataFrame(df2[0, :, :].squeeze())' might have placed it in the incorrect spot as I am not sure what this .squeeze() is actually doing.